# Optimizing python script to produce output faster (Variable Assignment)

Tags: python, performance, time

I am using python for optimization purposes. I made a graph using `Networkx` library with **1100** nodes. The python script includes the following lines.

```
# Compute key parameters of MIP model formulation
from itertools import product
num_facilities = len(facilities)
print("The num_facility = ", num_facilities)
num_customers = len(customers)
print("The num_customers = ", num_customers)
cartesian_prod = list(product(range(num_customers), range(num_facilities))) 

#Output
The num_facility =  1100
The num_customers =  1100
```

In the next step, some random numbers are generated as follows:

```
import random
random.seed(7) 
number_of_vpns = random.sample(range(0, 1200), num_facilities)
```

I compute the distance between nodes in the graph using the following function.

```
def compute_distance(source_number,dest_number):
    path = (nx.shortest_path(g,source=source_number,target= dest_number, weight='weight'))
    path_length = path_weight(g, path, weight="weight")
    return path_length
```

Finally, I defined the variable "***shipping_cost***" as:

```
%%time
shipping_cost = {(c,f): number_of_vpns[c]*compute_distance(c,f) for c, f in cartesian_prod}
```

Every line of the above code is executed in short manner (milliseconds). But, the assignment the value to the variable "shipping_cost" is not completed even after 7 hours. The variable logically contains 1210000 values.

1. Does it seem normal in terms of running time?
2. Is there any way to decrease the execution time of shipping_cost assignment?

Comment: What does ```cartesian_prod``` contain ? What does ```product``` do?

Comment: Dear @Ram, In the terms of Mathematics Cartesian Product of two sets is defined as the set of all ordered pairs (a, b) where a belongs to A and b belongs to B. Consider the below example for better understanding. The product comes from
```from itertools import product```
 Input : 
arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
arr2 = [5, 6, 7]
Output : [(1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7)]

Comment: Your ```cartesian_prod``` contains 1210000 values. You are calling ```compute_distance()``` which in turn calls ```shortest_path()``` and ```path_length()```for all the 1210000 values. That's the reason calculating ```shipping_cost``` takes lot of time to compute. Do you really need to calculate compute_distance() for all the values ?

Comment: And I suppose ```shortest_path()``` uses Dijkstra's algo whose time complexity is **O(ElogV)** and you have 1100 nodes(V = 1100) and I dont know about #edges. There's even ```path_length()``` - *I dont whats its time complexity*. I think you can do all the math and calculate the time taken for 1210000 values.

Comment: Just do the math. Lets assume 50 ms: `1210000 * 50 ms = 16.8 h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments by @Ram:

The `cartesian_prod` contains **1210000** values. The code is calling `compute_distance()` which in turn calls `shortest_path()` and `path_length()`for all the 1210000 values from `networkx` library. That's the reason calculating `shipping_cost` takes lot of time to compute.

I changed the code as follows (`path_lengths` is added instead of `compute_distance` and `shipping_cost` is modified):

```
import networkx as nx
path_lengths = dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(g, weight='weight'))

shipping_cost = {(c,f): number_of_vpns[c]*path_lengths[c][f] for c, f in cartesian_prod}
```

By doing so, the `path_lengths` is calculated once for all nodes, and the time complexity is focused on accessing the elements of path_lengths.